# How can I compile a C++ program and reference a framework installed with homebrew?

Tags: macos, compilation, frameworks, g++, homebrew

I want to compile this [program](https://github.com/jonnyhuck/Viewshed) on my mac os 10.15 system.

In the documentation the following command is given:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ viewshed.cpp -F/Library/Frameworks/ -framework GDAL -o viewshed -O3
```

So far I am not able to compile the program, since GDAL is not at the given location, because I have installed it via homebrew. As I found out [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285028/gdal-framework-does-not-exists-after-brew-install-cannot-locate-gdal-polygonize) homebrew as a different way to store its packages.

I found out that there is an alternative way to compile with pkg-config.

So I have tried to adapt the command (various times), this is the latest attempt:

```
g++ $(pkg-config std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  --cflags --libs gdal) viewshed.cpp -o viewshed -O3
```

But without success.

Can someone tell me how to compile the program successfully?

Comment: You need to get the `pkg-config` working on its own first! Try `pkg-config --cflags --libs gdal` and make sure you get something starting with `-I ...` and something starting with `-L...`

Comment: with `pkg-config --cflags --libs gdal` I am getting `-I/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_3/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.4.2_3/lib -lgdal`, what do I do further?

Comment: Good, now try `g++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -O3 viewshed.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gdal) -o viewshed`

Comment: It compiled. That is good. But I got 7 warnings. ...I am also not able to import the python package, after running the swig command...

Comment: How did you install `swig` and what exact `swig` command did you run?

Comment: I installed swig version 4.0.1 via homebrew and I copied the command given here https://github.com/jonnyhuck/Viewshed `swig -python -c++ viewshed.i; python setup.py build_ext --inplace

CFLAGS=-stdlib=libstdc++ `